# Ionic stateProvider - show/hide back button dynamically

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an Ionic app and I fully working left menu with working states.

Here's the menu code:

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-royal">
        <h1 class="title">Example</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item menu-close ng-repeat="test in data"
                      ng-switch="test.ID"
                      ng-href="{{test.ID == 0 ? '#/app/test' : '#/app/details/' + test.iID}}"
                      class="item item-icon-right">
                <div ng-switch-when="0"><span>{{test.Name}}</span></div>    
                <div ng-switch-default><span>{{test.Name}}</span>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>    
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

very basic setup.

and the code with the states (coffescript):

```
angular.module('hgApp', ['ionic'])
.config [
'$stateProvider'
'$urlRouterProvider'
($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
    $stateProvider.state('app',
       url: '/app'
       abstract: true
       templateUrl: './sections/menu/menu.html'
       controller: 'menuList'
    ).state('app.details',
       url: '/details/:testID'
       views:
         'menuContent':
             templateUrl: './sections/details/testDetails.html'
             controller: 'testDetails'
```

Now, here my problem:

I can navigate to `app/details/{testID}` from the list on the left menu, or from links that I have on my home page.

I need to be able to add a back button to the top bar of `app/details/{testID}` only if I got to the page using the links on the home page, but not if i got there from the left menu list.

both the menu list and the links on the home page use as href `"#/app/details/{{test.ID}}"`

How can I do that? I really have no clue at all.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i had a similar situation where i had to hide the button if the form was editable so i did the following

```
<ion-nav-back-button ng-show="!$root.hideBack"></ion-nav-back-button>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.makeEditable = function () {
    $scope.isEditable = true;
    $rootScope.hideBack = true;
};
```

so if the fields were editable the back button would dissapear. I hope this is of any help.

**Another example is:**

Use `$ionicHistory` in your controller before calling `$state.go('app.details')`. I guess you have different controller for Home page where you use `$stage.go` to go to the details page? so the code should look something like

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ["$scope", "$ionicHistory", function($scope, $ionicHistory) {

    $scope.goToDetails = function() {
      $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
        disableBack: true
      });
       $state.go('app.details');
    }

}]);
```

Html

```
<button ng-click="goToDetails()"></button>
```

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit better? I'm talking about the example using disableBack. It is now really clear from your answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer i hope it's a little clear this time.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question by the way

I think you can accomplish the behaviour you want using $broadcast

Basically you have a function that is called when you click on the link that will tell the testDetails controller 'hey, we came from a link, do your stuff'

The testDetails controller will be expecting this call and display the button accordingly

Raw code:

```
app.controller('AnyCtrl',
 function AnyCtrl ($scope) {
    // Call this code on link click
    $scope.$broadcast('fromlink', 'Some data');
});

app.controller('testDetails',
  function testDetails ($scope) {

  $scope.$on('fromlink', function (event, data) {
    // Add button. Profit
  });

});
```

You can find a link to a small article covering all possibilities here

https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/